# iTextSharp gives format error while opening the PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

HI I'm building an app that export information to PDF using iTextSharp.

It has a header, a footer and the body is a table. That could have several pages.

Everything is okey excepts when the table has few columns, like 2.

If the table has 5 or 6 columns, the PDF works ok.

When I have just 2 or 3 columns the Adobe Reader gives me the following error "There is an error on this page, Acrobat could not show it properly. Contact the person who create this PDF" (I translated the message from spanish, so it could be different to the original)

If I open the same file using Chrome it works ok.

This is how i add a cell:

```
 PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(ColumnValid);
                            t.WidthPercentage = 98;

 PdfPCell celda = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToString(cell.Value), font));
                                            celda.BorderWidth = 0;
                                            t.AddCell(celda);
```

Edit:

[Demo PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwqjRGXbFdZJaWV2bEpPUkhtZXc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please supply a sample pdf.

Comment: Also, are you writing to a `MemoryStream`?

Comment: I'm using a FileStream. I updated the comment to add a PDF example

Comment: Show us your full code, more specifically, your page events. For instance, the content stream of your page starts with:
`BT
0 742 Td
0 -420 Td
ET`
That's strange because: you have a text object for which no font is defined and no text is added. iText doesn't do this. You probably did.